# ¿Cómo clonar/copiar un archivo de nombre con caracteres reservados de un server hasta un almacenamiento local mediante Wget?

Tags: wget

Tengo un problema en mi trabajo, me asignaron la tarea de clonar/copiar masivamente unos archivos de un servidor de la empresa para hacer espacio en este por lo cual, de la totalidad de los archivos, tengo un 93% descargado y el resto pues... lo que sucede es que los archivos son de los clientes que suben adjuntos a algunos procesos que realizar pero casualmente los clientes suben estos archivos con caracteres reservados (Y curiosamente en la empresa donde trabajo, no controlaron esto para no tener problemas en el futuro)

Entonces, utilizo Wget y la línea de código es esta:

```
wget.exe -x -i "C:\clon\list.txt" -P "C:\clon\destino" -nv -o "C:\clon\log.txt"
```

En realidad no se que significan los parametros que se incorporan junto con las direcciones de origen/destino y las del log pero con esta línea de código la ejecutaba y descargaban en mi PC de trabajo, todos los archivos que se quería clonar pero hubieron unos cuentos que desgraciadamente no se descargaron.

Unos si los pude descargar ya que algunos poseían caracteres según el "HTML URL Encoding Reference" pero otros no se pero estuve investigando y nada... algunos archivos están nombrados con este carácter '}', otros vienen incluidos un signo de más '+' y bueno, creo que esto influye cuando se quiere descargar archivos hasta lo intente cargando dichos archivos desde el navergador pero resultaban en un error 404, pero buscandolos en el server SI QUE EXISTÍAN pero para no descargarlos manualmente ¿Habrá una manera más sencilla utilizando Wget? No se pero ignorar caracteres u otra manera pero nada

Intente colocarle estos parametros "--content-disposition" o "--restrict-file-names" pero nada.

Ejemplos de los archivos a los que me refiero:

- /FC04-6198}+.pdf
- /8+.pdf
- /PT05+2236.pdf

Comment: Desconozco cual es el formato de list.txt, intentaste tener entre comillas los nombres:
'/8+.pdf'

Comment: Bueno, cada línea del list.txt es una url del servidor y el archivo hosteado en el servidor (por ejemplo, https://ejemplo.com/files/12223/8+.pdf) y bueno, intente también colocar las comillas, tanto simples como dobles y nada, me salía esto "Unsopported Scheme" tras ejecutar el bat (Si, coloque la línea del wget en un archivo bat). Espero que ahora si quede claro.